# Will my website work with downstream browsers that don't support html5 if I use it for my layout?

Tags: html, html4

I want to lay out a website with html5 semantic markup. I'm wondering; if I use html5 and style the sections like I do with html4, will it still render properly? I don't want to use really up-to-date html5 stuff like canvas, I just want to future proof this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by using HTML5 Boilerplate.

It comes with Modernizr (which includes html5shiv), and a lot more as well.

[html5boilerplate.com](http://html5boilerplate.com)

Comment: So if I style a html5 element this code will mean it will still work in older browsers? That may be obvious I just want to make totally sure before I start...thanks....

Comment: Yes. Try this link: http://shaquin.tk/experiments/html5test.html. It has HTML5 elements <header>, <nav>, and <footer>, and a <p>. Try rendering it in [IE NetRenderer](http://netrenderer.com) as IE 6. Only the <p> will be styled.  Now try http://shaquin.tk/experiments/html5test.html?ie-fix in IE NetRenderer. All HTML5 elements are styled. Just remember to use the lt IE 9 conditional comment. :)

Comment: @Exitos - Did you get my comment? I forgot to add @ at the start.

Comment: yes I got your comment. Not sure why people need to add @[name] when simply [name] would do. This is a twitter thing no? Anyway thankyou!

Answer (score 1):

Any HTML5 specific tags (such as `<nav>` or `<header>`) will be ignored by the browser. The raw tags won't appear on the page (you won't get the word `<nav>` appearing or etc), but they simply won't do anything. Note that any styles applied to them also won't work - I found this out the hard way. If you want to style a nav bar, then don't style the `<nav>` tag; style the `<div>` or similar tag inside it.

As for HTML5 'utilities' such as `<video>` or similar, you're better off using a Javascript library that detects the browsers capabilities and uses the appropriate code. [Jplayer](http://jplayer.org), for example, allows you to embed video and audio that uses HTML5 if available, and Flash if not, while still using the same HTML interface.

If you want a really show-off feature like a Canvas-powered system, then it's best not to use this for the main area of your site, and just add a little note saying "Please upgrade to a modern browser to view this properly" if you can detect it's not working (which is possible by using `var check=document.createElement('canvas')` then checking whether the value is undefined.

Comment: In IE6, `<nav>`, `<header>`, etc. will still show on the page, but cannot be styled without html5shiv.

Comment: I meant you won't see the raw text "`<nav>`" or etc appear on the page. Edited to make clearer.

Answer (score 1):

You can definitely do this with the use of a shim - this will allow you to use all the HTML5 semantic tags and will convert them for older browsers. Check out html5shim here: http://code.google.com/p/html5shim/

and just include it in your code how they show:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="dist/html5shiv.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```